# JQ How to replace entire array with a variable arg

Tags: json, variables, arguments, jq

So I can do this

```
jq --arg title "Test" 'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = [{"uid":"foo"},{"uid":"bar"}]' json
```

Which outputs the desired results:

```
{
  "alert": {
    "notifications": [
      { 
        "uid": "foo" 
      },
      { 
        "uid": "bar" 
      }
    ]
  },
  "title": "Test"
}
```

However, I need to put the array in a var and supply it on the fly instead, like:

```
array='{ "uid": "foo" },{ "uid": "bar"}'

jq -r --arg title "$t" --arg array "$array" 'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = [$array]'
```

But that results in this undesired output

```
{
  "alert": {
    "notifications": [
      "{ \"uid\": \"foo\" },{ \"uid\": \"bar\" }"
    ]
  },
  "title": "Test"
}
```

Any way to get around this? Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `--argjson` (instead of `--arg`) for JSON input. Note, however, that `{"uid": "foo" }, {"uid": "bar"}` by itself is not (yet) valid JSON. You need to wrap it into brackets to make it an array (otherwise, `jq` will (rightfully) complain about a superfluous comma between the two objects).

Brackets added to the string provided for `--argjson`:

```sh
array='{"uid": "foo" }, {"uid": "bar"}'

jq --arg title "$t" --argjson array "[$array]" \
  'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = $array'
```

Brackets added to the shell variable called `array`:

```sh
array='[{"uid": "foo" }, {"uid": "bar"}]'

jq --arg title "$t" --argjson array "$array" \
  'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = $array'
```

Also note that if your output is JSON, you don't need the `-r` option.

```json
{
  "alert": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "uid": "foo"
      },
      {
        "uid": "bar"
      }
    ]
  },
  "title": "Test"
}
```

---

If you don't have the option to use `--argjson` instead of `--arg` (because, for example, the input may or may not be JSON and you can only test it *after* populating the variables), you can use the `fromjson` builtin to convert a JSON-encoded string into actual JSON (said "testing" is not included in these examples).

Brackets added inline just before applying `fromjson`:

```sh
array='{"uid": "foo" }, {"uid": "bar"}'

jq --arg title "$t" --arg array "$array" \
  'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = ("[\($array)]" | fromjson)'
```

Brackets added to the string provided for `--arg`:

```sh
array='{"uid": "foo" }, {"uid": "bar"}'

jq --arg title "$t" --arg array "[$array]" \
  'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = ($array | fromjson)'
```

Brackets added to the shell variable called `array`:

```sh
array='[{"uid": "foo" }, {"uid": "bar"}]'

jq --arg title "$t" --arg array "$array" \
  'select(.title == $title) | .alert.notifications = ($array | fromjson)'
```